# Execute multiple queries with parameters on a single connection using jdbc template

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, mssql-jdbc

I need to execute multiple queries via jdbc template in a single connection.
I am using SQL server with the mssql jdbc driver. Here is the query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NULL
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM ( SELECT * FROM "complex query here" ) a

DECLARE @page_size INT
SET @page_size = ?

SELECT *
       FROM ( SELECT TOP(@page_size) * FROM #temp
                                       WHERE custom_column > ?
                                       ORDER BY custom_column ) inner_query
(MULTIPLE JOINES HERE)
ORDER BY custom_column
```

The query simply puts the whole result from the complex query to the temp table if the table does not exist and selects pages from the generated temp table.
Since the temp tables have connection scope, i need to execute the whole paging with multiple queries in a single connection. This is the code i have tried:

```
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        while (true) {

          List<CustomObject> customObjects = customRepository.
              .getCustomObjectsPage(connection, pageSize, minimumValueInWhere);

          // business logic here..

          if (customObjects.size() < pageSize) {
            break;
          }

          minimumValueInWhere = customObjects.get(customObjects.size() - 1).getId().toString();
        }
      }
```

and getCustomObjectsPage():

```
public List<CustomObject> getCustomObjectsPage(Connection connection, int pageSize,
      String parameter) {
    JdbcTemplate singleConnectionJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(
        new SingleConnectionDataSource(connection, true));

    try {
      return singleConnectionJdbcTemplate
          .query("the query from above", new Object[]{pageSize, parameter},
              JdbcTemplateMapperFactory.newInstance()
                  .newResultSetExtractor(CustomObject.class)); // the root entity.
    } 
  }
```

But for some reasons the queries are not executed in a single connection, and if i hardcode the 
parameters to the query instead of passing them to the jdbc template it works perfectly.

How to make this work independently of the parameters ?

Comment: Just execute them in a transaction which will reuse the same connection. You are making things overly complex.

Comment: Are you trying to hold a connection open so that the user can make multiple page requests to your website and retrieve the same temp table and page through it? Don't

Comment: @CaiusJard no, the whole paging is triggered in one request and it's okay.

Comment: @M.Deinum but i need to select and do some business logic with each page. How can i do that in a single transaction ?

Comment: Inthe comment before this you mention that it applies to a single request with multiple queryies and now it doesn't? Which is it? When using a tx it will use the same connection for all queries in that transaction. If you want to keep a connection open in between requests, as mentioned don't.

Comment: I'm still curious then why you don't just download  x records, work with them, download x more, work with them. Why try this complex page when you can just pull 200 records at a time out of the reader?

Comment: Because it is around 60% faster with a temp table, I have tested it and the performance is crucial in this scenario for me.

Comment: @M.Deinum I meant single http request triggers multiple database requests (The same queries with different parameters for the paging) one by one(i need to do some logic with the result of each of these queries), so i need the connection open between database requests as with temp table is faster. Can i solve this with tx?

Comment: as stated twice before execute all those statements in a single transaction and you will have the same connection.

Comment: Anyways, this has nothing to do with users, or requests - I have no idea why you are mentioning that. What I’m trying to do, is execute a complex query that has a very high execution time and returns a large amount of objects that won’t fit in memory. Which is why I store the result in a temp table database side, and try to re-use the connection (so the temp table persists) to fetch remaining pages.